# How do I get a list of tokens held by an Ethereum address?

Tags: tokens, ether, addresses, etherscan

TL;DR: wanted: a method that receives an address as a parameter and returns an array of token names/contracts/balances held by address.

I'm aware of the fact that Etherscan API has a method allowing you to see the balance of an address, when you supply the contract taddress of a token. My question is: how do I get a list of tokens an address hold?

Case in point: when you go to Etherscan, there's a dropdown, showing a list of tokens and balances. Surely it is not the case (I hope) that Etherscan iterates through all known token contracts to look for the address?

How can I build such a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what Etherscan does - they have a list of tokens that they track. You'll then have to do a `balanceOf` query on each token with the address you want to get balance for.

There is no central repository of token balances, since they are all their own individual contracts that just contain user balances.

Edit: If you're querying balances directly from the chain, you can also use [this](https://github.com/wbobeirne/eth-balance-checker/blob/master/src/common.ts) balance checker library. You can query the contract directly [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb1f8e55c7f64d203c1400b9d8555d050f94adf39#readContract). Just pass a list of accounts and tokens and it will automatically return the list of the balances for each account on each token with one API call.

Comment: But such a list is (potentially) infinite (ok, no infinite-infinite, but a very large possible number). Am I expected to keep a huge list of contract addresses and iterate through all of them, calling the API for each?

Comment: Yup, that's the only way. Etherscan of course has all this data cached, so they don't have to query every token every time you view your account on etherscan

Comment: Shame, but I guess that's life :) I'll just maintain a list of major token contracts, and allow users to add more. Of course, that's now one extra API call per token...

Comment: There is also an easy way around the "one API call per token", see my edit

Comment: I believe it just does the same thing: it still needs to query n accounts with m1...mn contracts, and check the blockchain m1+m2+...mn times. I don't think there's any "magic" shortcut. I ended up writing  a module that accepts a list of addresses, goes over all transactions, gets a unique list of contracts and checks the balances of each on the account. Realizing that Etherscan limits you to 5 calls/second was a fun part of the development process...

Comment: No, it only does 1 network request. On the nodes side, it does all the individual balance queries locally, which is extremely fast

Comment: Well, my problem is: I now the list of accounts, I don't know the list of tokens. So I still need to get the list of all transactions per account, and sift out the token contracts. And each account may have different tokens, so there's no "single list".

Comment: Why get list of transactions and sift through the token cibtracts? You still have to "maintain a list of major token contracts" separately. Then you can just use the balancer checker for the full list of tokens against the full list of accounts (or do x accounts per call if you have thousands of accounts). Some balances will return 0, that's fine

Comment: Not sure I understand. The requirement is this: given an array of addresses, show total $ value of each address. I need to get a list of every token the address holds. Rather than go through every token known and ask if the address has it (with a balance > 0), what I currently do is go through past transactions, and collect token contact addresses. How would you optimize?